# Using Google Maps Offline

Tags: asp.net, google-maps-api-3, offline

I need to utilize the Google Maps API.  I just found out a minute ago though, that it requires a key, therefor rendering useless until the site is online.  I can't constantly upload the site every time I test a change because it could break some of the pages if I make a mistake.  In fact, at this point in time, I don't have a hoster or a domain name because my client has yet to decide on where he wants to host it.  I have to have the site 100% complete to show him the entire functionality.

How do I develop the Google Maps part without having it hosted online?

I'm using it in ASP.net...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just go to the [API Key signup page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html) and request a key for `http://localhost`.

I haven't tested it myself, but from what I read it works perfectly this way.

Comment: *facepalm*  I tried something similar but omitted the `http://` and when it didn't work, I assumed it was because I tried doing it via localhost.  Guess I was just dumb.  Thanks a ton!  I'll mark you as write when SO lets me :) **EDIT** I would also like to point out that you have **666** points as of right now....

Comment: Heh, yeah. Thanks for getting me away from this evil number. :)

Comment: I just wanted to know that using the localhost key would allow me to use the "API" when internet is not working? I mean if the map is already with me, and then the internet connection goes off, would I be able to use the "API"?